# Anyone know of an abstraction layer for JavaScript libraries for common tasks?

Tags: javascript, frameworks, abstraction

I know, I know, another layer on top of the libraries, but I think there could be some benefits when it comes to porting certain functionality. I thought I would ask and see if anyone has found anything related to this. Essentially it would be a bunch of getters and setters, and any one of the major libraries could sit inbetween. Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: maybe give an example of the sort of code this layer might help you write?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this probably isn't exactly what you're looking for, but there are bridges to either [jQuery](http://soc.our.psu.edu/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/ext/docs/output/jquery-bridge.jss.html) or [Prototype](http://soc.our.psu.edu/CFIDE/scripts/ajax/ext/docs/output/prototype-bridge.jss.html) for the ExtJS library.  So with those bridges, you can end up with one of three libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://www.tysoncadenhead.com/blog/do-javascript-libraries-need-an-abstraction-layer) is what you're talking about.  Am I right?  I don't think there's anything like that out there.  Every application has different needs, so having an entire library around this would be a lot of code for something that doesn't really need that much code.  I would say this would be something you would need to write yourself in order to keep it minimal and to best serve your needs.